# Archive mail for multiple Gmail accounts

Tags: gmail

Sometimes my colleague and me both get the same email to solve a problemn
It happened multiple times that we both solved the problem, which is a complete waste.

To solve this I want the following:
If I archive the mail, it is also archived in his mail box.
And the other way around.

Can this be done?
Preferably without scripting

Comment: You need a shared account, or a ticketing system

Comment: @user11817602  this is an issue specific to a web based application, You may find an answer more rapidly at our site for web based apps, http://webapps.stackexchange.com

Comment: @ivanivan so this can be done if I make an alias "sales@reekmansverandabouw.be" and my colleague gets access to it?

Comment: What you want is a true shared account that you can each access that uses the same inbox, sent, drafts, etc.  How to do this depends on how/where your mail server is hosted.